# tinymce 4.0.12 editor blank (but textarea has data)

Tags: jquery, tinymce

On my page I have textarea field in a for loop:

```
<textarea data-type="wys_editor" id="{{ prefix }}{{ key }}" name="{{ key }}">{{ item.value }}</textarea>
```

When I init tinymce like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  tinymce.init({
     selector: "textarea[data-type=wys_editor]",
    });        
});
```

I have an editor, but it's blank. When I inspect this elements in Chrome, after tinymce div's I have a textarea with my data, but tinymce editor still empty, please help!

How can I fix this?

Comment: is that the full initialisation code? you're missing some closing brakcets

Comment: You might need to add the loop code